# Pagination in Ascending Order

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have this mysql query that displays records in ascending order by time. (Older -> Newer)

`SELECT * FROM $conversation_reply WHERE c_id_fk='$c_id' ORDER BY time ASC`

The above query displays records like below

`1 - 12mn
2 - 1am
3 - 2am
4 - 3am
5 - 5am
6 - 6am
7 - 7am
8 - 8am`

Now i want to have a simple pagination with only "NEXT" to use on jquery infinite scroll,

For example:
At page 1,

`5 - 5am
6 - 6am
7 - 7am
8 - 8am`

And at page 2,

`1 - 12mn
2 - 1am
3 - 2am
4 - 3am`

How to accomplish this? It is different from a usual pagination which displays records from newer to older.

Answer (score 0):

variables

```
$start = 0; // it means will start from the first record
$limit = 10; // it means return 10 record each page
```

mysql

```
SELECT * FROM $conversation_reply WHERE c_id_fk = '$c_id' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT $start, $limit
```

Example

```
**PAGE 1**
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

**PAGE 2**
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
```

but dont forget to make it dynamic, so the mysql will be looks like

```
**PAGE 1**
SELECT * FROM $conversation_reply WHERE c_id_fk = '$c_id' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 0, 10

**PAGE 2**
SELECT * FROM $conversation_reply WHERE c_id_fk = '$c_id' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10, 10
```

Comment: Could you add some explaining sentences regarding the parameters that you have introduced?

Comment: How do i implement start?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. But i found `array_reverse` to be my solution.